# A finitely generated torsional free module A over a principal ideal domain is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In am studying algebra from Textbook Thomas Hungerford and I am struck on an argument in a theorem on page 247 .

It's image :

[image]

Question: How does one can be sure about existence of non empty set S which is maximal with respect to mentioned property in line 3 of proof?

I thought of assuming that let such an maximal set doesn't exist. Then I am getting an infinite set whose elements are linearly independent but what's the contradiction as they may not generate the whole A.

Kindly guide!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see it is to think about how you would build $S$.  Note that we've started with a *finite* set $X$ that generates $A$.  Since we've already assumed $A \neq 0$, then certainly $X \neq \emptyset$, so pick any $x_1 \in X$.  Then $\{x_1\}$ has the property that you want.  Now if $\{x_1\}$ is maximal then great, you're done.  If not, find an $x_2 \in X$ such that $\{x_1, x_2\}$ still has the property.  Again, if $\{x_1, x_2\}$ is maximal for your property, then you're done.  Otherwise, continue.  You'll have to stop eventually, because $X$ is finite, and when you stop you've got the $S$ you wanted.